# Get table parameter and save in meta value

Tags: post-meta, wpdb

I want to get `number_1` and `number_2` and save in `meta_value` in table `wp_postmeta`. How do I do the same? The `id_help_i` and the same of the `$post-> ID`. Some id of the table `wp_table_help_i` does not have the parameters `number_1` and `number_2` the ones that do not have I would like to add an example value 99999 from already thank you

sorry bad english

```
 function update_my_metadata() {


            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post', // Only get the posts
                'post_status' => 'publish', // Only the posts that are published
                'posts_per_page' => -1 // Get every post
            );


            $posts = get_posts($args);
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                global $wpdb;
                $meta_value = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT Number_1 + Number_2 FROM wp_table_help_i WHERE id_help_i = '$post->ID'", $id));
                // Run a loop and update every meta data
                update_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key', $meta_value);
            }
        }

            // Hook into init action and run our function
            add_action('init', 'update_my_metadata');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that if you leave this on the init action, this will occur on every page load. If you only want this to occur once or during another action, you'll need to change this.

This will also timeout if you try to execute this on too many posts.

```
function update_my_metadata() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post', // Only get the posts
        'post_status'    => 'publish', // Only the posts that are published
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get every post
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            global $wpdb;
            $number_one = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT Number_1 FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_help_i WHERE id_help_i = %d", $post->ID ) );
            $number_two = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT Number_2 FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_help_i WHERE id_help_i = %d", $post->ID ) );
        if ( ! empty( $number_one ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_meta_key_name', $number_one );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $number_two ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_meta_key_name', $number_two  );
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'update_my_metadata');
```

Comment: Thank you very much works.
Know how I add a number to the $post-> ID not found in table_help_i ?

Comment: para a 'your_meta_key_name' 1 number for all not found

Comment: Thanks a lot I solved